# After obtaining an ODE solution, why can I not introduce a new function definition?

Tags: function-construction

#### Edit

```
Clear["`*"];smax=0.854;m=1.5;
EQ={(SI'[s]*Tan[SI[s]]*Tan[PH[s]]+PH'[s]+2 R[s] Cos[PH[s]]/Cos[SI[s]])/(m^2-R[s]^2)==0,(PH'[s] Cos[SI[s]])==m (R[s]Cos[SI[s]]),R'[s]==Sin[PH[s]]Cos[SI[s]],PH[0]==.98,SI[0]==1.2,R[0]==1.3};
NDSolve[EQ,{PH,SI,R},{s,0,smax}];
{ph[s_],si[s_],r[s_]}={PH[s],SI[s],R[s]}/.First[%];
k1[s_]=ph'[s]/Cos[si[s]];
k2[s_]=Cos[ph[s]]/r[s];
knM[s_]=k1[s] Cos[si[s]]^2+k2[s]Sin[si[s]]^2;
plugin[s_]=ph'[s] Cos[si[s]]+Cos[ph[s]]/r[s]Sin[si[s]]^2;
g1=Plot[plugin[s],{s,0,smax},PlotLabel->"EQ11"]
g2=Plot[knM[s],{s,0,smax},PlotLabel->"EQ22"]
Show[{g1,g2},PlotRange->All,PlotLabel->"SHOW_BOTH"]
g3=Plot[plugin[s]-knM[s],{s,0,smax},PlotLabel->"SHOW_DIFFERENCE"]
```

After substitution of two defined functions a different result follows. That is my actual question here.

EDIT: Clear["`*"] in first line indicated by xzczd overcomes the problem.

[image: FnError Remaining]

Comment: 1.`ClearAll;` won't do the job you want to do, check its document carefully. 2. `k1[s_]` and `k2[s_]` should be `k1[u_]` and `k2[u_]`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out error.However, my query is about more severe disturbance of computation. Plots titled EQ11 and EQ22 are different, they still need to be reconciled.

Comment: In `g1` you wrote `Cos[ph[s]/r[s]]`, while in `k2` you wrote `Cos[ph[u]]/r[u]`. The difference is once again the result of simple mistake.

Comment: As a matter of fact there is/was no mistake. Imho function arguments are arbitrary.

Comment: Notice It's `Cos[ph[…]/r[…]]` vs `Cos[ph[…]]/r[…]`!

Comment: You're still using `ClearAll` in the wrong way, once again, please check the document carefully. And, if you still don't see my point, press **Ctrl + Shift + N** to transform your expression to 2D-form and observe `k1` and `plugin`.

Comment: It is not that. The error is elsewhere. For clarity, I have written plugin[s] function separately for all arguments labeled [s] as above. I request you to give a corrected code where this error is avoided and works correctly as you indicated.

Comment: Check my edit to your code.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks a lot, it works. (Clear["`*"]) is more effective. Also appreciate your concern expressed on meta "Can we improve tag DE".. Thanking once again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment of functions that you made to the output of `NDSolve` is fine in principle.

```
{ph[u_], si[u_], r[u_]} = {PH[u], SI[u], R[u]} /. First[%]
```

The danger is that you may have typed something between running `NDSolve` and executing the above statement. For that reason I recommend assigning the output of `NDSolve` to a variable. Also one doesn't have to re-run NDSolve everytime you want to experiement with the output.

As an aside, it is not recommended to use uppper case letters for symbols, it might collide with pre-defined Mathematica symbols. Also I recommend the user of `SetDelayed` (`:=`) rather than `Set` (`=`) when creating your functions. I didn't do that, but strongly advise that it is better.

```
smax = 0.854;
m = 1.5;

EQ = {(SI'[s]*Tan[SI[s]]*Tan[PH[s]] + PH'[s] + 
       2 R[s] Cos[PH[s]]/Cos[SI[s]])/(m^2 - R[s]^2) == 
    0, (PH'[s] Cos[SI[s]] + 0) == m (R[s] Cos[SI[s]]), 
   R'[s] == Sin[PH[s]] Cos[SI[s]], PH[0] == .98, SI[0] == 1.2, 
   R[0] == 1.3};
```

Assign the output to a symbol

```
sol = NDSolve[EQ, {PH, SI, R}, {s, 0, smax}]

(* {{PH -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.854}}, <>], 
  SI -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.854}}, <>], 
  R -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.854}}, <>]}} *)
```

There are multiple ways of assigning the output of `NDSolve` to functions.

One way (using `Part`) is shown below. Examine the parts of `sol`.

```
sol[[1, 1]]

(* PH -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.854}}, <>] *)
```

In order to get to the actual `InterpolatingFunction` we need to go one more level.

```
sol[[1, 1, 2]]

(* InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.854}}, <>] *)
```

Now make the assignments for the functions:

```
{ph[u_], si[u_], r[u_]} = {sol[[1, 1, 2]][u], 
                           sol[[1, 2, 2]][u],
                           sol[[1, 3, 2]][u]}

(* {InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.854}}, <>][u], 
 InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.854}}, <>][u], 
 InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 0.854}}, <>][u]} *)
```

Alternatively, using your procedure, you can elegantly write:

```
{ph[u_], si[u_], r[u_]} = {PH[u], SI[u], R[u]} /. First[sol]
```

### Duplicate your functions and plots

```
k1[s_] = ph'[s]/Cos[si[s]]
k2[s_] = Cos[ph[s]]/r[s]
knM[s_] = k1[s] Cos[si[s]]^2 + k2[s] Sin[si[s]]^2
plugin[s_] = ph'[s] Cos[si[s]] + Cos[ph[s]]/r[s] Sin[si[s]]^2
```

Plot the composite function

```
g1 = Plot[plugin[s], {s, 0, smax}, PlotLabel -> "EQ11", 
          PlotStyle -> Black]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
g2 = Plot[knM[s], {s, 0, smax}, PlotLabel -> "EQ22", 
          PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Show[{g1, g2}, PlotRange -> All, PlotLabel -> "SHOW_BOTH"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
g3 = Plot[plugin[s] - knM[s], {s, 0, smax}, 
          PlotLabel -> "SHOW_DIFFERENCE", PlotStyle -> Black]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Results appear to be identical

Comment: Plots of EQ11 and EQ22 are not same.

Comment: Thanks. Part assignments are better to be used rather than [%].

Comment: @Narasimham I updated in accordance with your edit and get identical results

Comment: Fine, so the standard way  carefully done is also valid.